# How to set username and password for particular days?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

Using VB.NET and SQL Server 2005

In my software I am using login page with UserName and Password. Suppose I am setting a username and password work for 20 days. After 20 days, when I try to login in software, the software should not to allow to login.

Is possible to make a SQL query or VB.NET code.

Can any one provide a sample code or query for the username and password should work for particular days?

Comment: Will all users be expiring after the same number of days or will that amount of time vary based on user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using ASP .Net's builtin membership and roles functionality.  Without modifying any of the existing tables, or extending that functionality, you could [create a SQL Server Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx) that executes the following statement:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership]
   SET [IsLockedOut] = 1
WHERE CreateDate <= DateAdd(Day, -20, GetDate())
```

This will lock out users that were created 20 or more days ago.  You will need to have the SQL Server Agent service running to do this.  This obviously doesn't provide flexibility to specify a different lockout time for different users.  You could easily extend the where clause to exclude certain users from ever getting locked out.

A more flexible (though involved) alternative would be to [define a profile property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8b58y5d.aspx) for your expiration date.  If you are using the ASP .Net CreateUserWizard control, you could hook in to the UserCreated event and set the expiration profile property to whatever date you wanted.  Then, it's just a matter of checking that property when the user logs in by hooking in to the Login control's LoggingIn or LoggedIn event(s).  If the current date is greater than the expiration date then cancel the log in, and present the user with a message as to why they were denied.

I'll see if I can put together a sample project.

Hacked this together at lunch.  Uses the profile to store expiration.  Again, assuming you're using the ASP .Net and Sql membership provider.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                Thanks for logging in.&nbsp; Your account will expire on:<br />
                &nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lblExpiration" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
            </LoggedInTemplate>
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                You are not currently logged in.&nbsp; Log in or create a new user.<br />
                <br />
            </AnonymousTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#EFF3FB" 
            BorderColor="#B5C7DE" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333">
            <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
            <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#507CD1" 
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
                ForeColor="#284E98" />
            <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" 
                ForeColor="Black" />
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Login>
        <br />
        <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderColor="#B5C7DE" 
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="0.8em">
            <SideBarStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Size="0.9em" 
                VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <SideBarButtonStyle BackColor="#507CD1" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="White" />
            <ContinueButtonStyle BackColor="White" 
                BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#284E98" />
            <NavigationButtonStyle BackColor="White" 
                BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#284E98" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#284E98" BorderColor="#EFF3FB" 
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" 
                ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <CreateUserButtonStyle BackColor="White" 
                BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#284E98" />
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="White" />
            <StepStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" />
                <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:CreateUserWizard>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.lblError.Visible = False

        If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = True Then
            'is the user's account expired? if so log them out.
            If Profile.Expiration <= Now Then
                Me.lblError.Visible = True
                Me.lblError.Text = "Your account has expired.  Please contact the administrator or create a new account."
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString)
            Else
                CType(LoginView1.FindControl("lblExpiration"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label).Text = Profile.Expiration.ToString
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CreateUserWizard1.CreatedUser
        Dim p As ProfileCommon
        p = ProfileCommon.Create(CreateUserWizard1.UserName)

        p.Expiration = Now.AddMinutes(2)
        p.Save()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Login1_LoggingIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs) Handles Login1.LoggingIn
        'get the user's profile and check their expiration date
        Profile.GetProfile(Login1.UserName)

        If Profile.Expiration <= Now Then
            Me.lblError.Visible = True
            Me.lblError.Text = "Your account has expired.  Please contact the administrator or create a new account."
            'cancel the login attempt
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.

            Visual Basic options:
            Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
            where data loss can occur. 
            Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <clear/>
                <add namespace="System"/>
                <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
                <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
                <add namespace="System.Text"/>
                <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
                <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
                <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
            </namespaces>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Forms"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
            <properties>
                <add name="Expiration" type="System.DateTime"/>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Hope that helps.  Any questions just ask.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a table that says:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(
  Username VARCHAR(128),
  Password VARCHAR(16),
  LastReset SMALLDATETIME
);
```

(Keeping it simple here, you probably want to store a hash of the password and compare a hash to the entry, rather than store the password in plain text.)

Now, when the user logs in, you check the LastReset column for that user.  If it is more than 20 days ago, force them to reset the password, and when they do, update the LastReset column to DATEADD(DAY, 20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Comment: But, The client should not able to open the users table. How to set

Comment: The client doesn't open anything.  How are you currently checking their login and password when they log in?  How are you currently creating a new user and setting their password?  Those are the stored procedures that would change so that your application behaves the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column in the member's table that specify an expiration date for the password..

When you query the database on login, you add a condition in the WHERE to check if the current time is not greater that the expiration date...

`SELECT * FROM Member WHERE email = 'dfsdfsd' AND password = 'ddada' AND expiration > GETDATE()`

This way, user wont be able to log in when the password expires

edit: the way you determine "expiration" is up to you... you could set GETDATE() + 20 on user insertion in the DB

Thanks

Comment: But, The client should not able to open the member table. How to set

Comment: what do you mean the client? if it is your software, you change it! It is like adding any other business rule to your application...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what technology you are using (ASP.NET/Windows forms), but if you are using the Membership Provider, you will find that has a [LastPasswordChangedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastpasswordchangeddate.aspx) that you will find useful.

If you are using .NET 3.5 you can use this in Windows forms by using [client application services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx) as well as [ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) easily.